# How to remove a untracked folder from the current branch, which is required for the another branch?

Tags: git, github

Say i have two branches (A and B) and a folder name "B"
The "B" folder is only required for branch B not for branch A. But whenever i checkout to branch A. The "B" folder is listed in the untracked files.

I know i can add the folder name to .gitignore in branch A. But what if i have 10 branches and i require a particular file/folder in only one branch . Should i have to update the .gitignore in all other 9 branches?. Is there any alternative way?

I'm sorry if the question sounds silly. Am just a beginner in git.

Comment: What kind of content is stored in this folder ? dlls ? images ? config files ? ...

Comment: If your folder appears as untracked in branch A, it may be because it contains untracked files. If that is the case, either commit these files in branch A or ignore them in all branches.

Comment: The directory contains a python modules.

Comment: Is the python module tracked?

Comment: Nope. The folder and its contents falls are untracked. But when i had the folder to .gitignore it works as i expected.